# SQL Insert Dates every 7 days for 10 years

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008

I am trying to script a query that inserts a date into a table every 7 days for the next 10 years. This will prevent me from having to have to type these dates by hand.

Is there a way to specify a start date and add 7 days to that date on each insert until the end date is reached?

Attached is my query. not sure where to being on this one. Any help is most appreciated.

```
declare @startDate date
declare @endDate date

set @startDate='2015-01-03'
set @endDate='2015-01-04'

INSERT INTO TimePeriod (YearsA)
VALUES ('2015-01-03'),
       ('2015-01010'),
       (etc.)
       ('2025-01-04)
```

Comment: you want insert every day date up to 10 years into a table

Comment: Once you have inserted rows for next 10 years , next week you will only be out a week not 10 years? your table would only need another week's worth of dates not another 10 year's

Comment: Why not just add another 20 years dates and you will not need to insert rows for another 10 years ?

Comment: My results should look like row 1  01-03-205, row2  01-10-2015, row3 01-17-2015, etc, etc for 10 years. So I just keep adding 7 days to the previous date until the end date is reached. that maybe 10 years maybe more.... I just need every saturday's date in each row .. if this makes sense

Comment: I am just wondering if there is a script where i could loop through the dates and add 7 days while continuously inserting those dates into a table for as long as my end date specifies

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The below query will give you weekend dates for till `2042-05-17` years.

```
 SELECT DISTINCT DATEADD(DAY,  - DATEPART(WEEKDAY, DayNumber), CAST(DayNumber AS DATE))
FROM(
      SELECT TOP (10000) 
           DATEADD(DAY 
                 ,ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY (SELECT NULL)) -1
                 , CAST(YEAR(GETDATE()) AS VARCHAR(4)) + '0101' )  DayNumber
      From master..spt_values x Cross Join master..spt_values y 
     )x
 ORDER BY DATEADD(DAY,  - DATEPART(WEEKDAY, DayNumber), CAST(DayNumber AS DATE))
```

### Result

```
2015-01-03
2015-01-10
2015-01-17
2015-01-24
2015-01-31
2015-02-07
2015-02-14
2015-02-21
2015-02-28
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use recursive CTE to get all the dates:
try;

```
declare @startDate date
declare @endDate date

set @startDate='2015-03-01' -- YYYY-MM-DD format
set @endDate='2015-04-01'

;with all_date as (
    select @startDate Dates
    union all
    select DATEADD(day, 7, Dates)
    from all_date
    where Dates < @endDate
)
INSERT INTO TimePeriod (YearsA)
select Dates from all_date
```