# SQL - Insert dates in a field between a date range

Tags: sql, date, datetime, amazon-redshift, sql-insert

I am trying to insert a `date` in a field every `7 days` between year `2021` and `2023`
This is for me not to insert it manually several times. I can't find any related post here in stack so I decided to ask since I really need this task.

Appreciate your answer or any reference that might help me through this.

EDIT: My bad, It is `amazon redshift`

Comment: Your bad, indeed.  You tagged the wrong database.

Comment: @TimBiegeleisen Thanks! I was able to get the right value using your demo. Did a little tweak to match postgre's syntax.

Answer (score 1):

```
declare @startDate date
declare @endDate date
set @startDate='2021-03-01' -- YYYY-MM-DD format
set @endDate='2023-04-01'

;with all_date as (
    select @startDate Dates
    union all
    select DATEADD(day, 7, Dates)
    from all_date
    where Dates < @endDate
)
INSERT INTO [Table_name]([column])
select Dates from all_date
```

You can use like this ...

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32408464/sql-insert-dates-every-7-days-for-10-years  for ref

Answer (score 0):

Thanks to [Tim Biegeleisen](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1863229/tim-biegeleisen) answer but unfortunately I stated that I'm using `MySQL` instead of `Amazon Redshift` and he deleted his answer. That was a mistake on my part.
I tweaked his answer and was able generate proper dates that I needed.

```
select * from 
(select cast(DATEADD(day, 7*(t4*10000 + t3*1000 + t2*100 + t1*10 + t0), '2022-01-03') as date) wk_start from
 (select 0 t0 union select 1 union select 2 union select 3 union select 4 union select 5 union select 6 union select 7 union select 8 union select 9) t0,
 (select 0 t1 union select 1 union select 2 union select 3 union select 4 union select 5 union select 6 union select 7 union select 8 union select 9) t1,
 (select 0 t2 union select 1 union select 2 union select 3 union select 4 union select 5 union select 6 union select 7 union select 8 union select 9) t2,
 (select 0 t3 union select 1 union select 2 union select 3 union select 4 union select 5 union select 6 union select 7 union select 8 union select 9) t3,
 (select 0 t4 union select 1 union select 2 union select 3 union select 4 union select 5 union select 6 union select 7 union select 8 union select 9) t4) v
where wk_start < '2024-01-03'
order by wk_start
```

I added `cast` just to remove the `hours,min,secs` in its format. In this way I can insert the result into my table